# magento 2 setup:static-content:deploy memory error

Tags: magento2, cli

I am trying to install quick setup of theme also did but css and js is not loading so i run command.
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
    but every time getting error like memory error
and also getting error related to execution time
    is there any solution?

Comment: Which type of memory error ?

Comment: now having execution time error

Comment: Which  execution time error ?

Comment: only execution time error not any type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass memory limit parameter.

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: i try this working.but now i am getting error for execution time now